# Console application to search for files that contain a match for a regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I created a small console application to recursively search a folder and all subfolders for files that contain a match for a regex.

The command line arguments are the path you're looking to search followed by the regex (in .NET regex format).

I break this up into two threads: the main thread loops through the files and puts file data (their content, path, and name) on a concurrent queue. The second thread processes the queue, looking for regex matches.

Would using a `Parallel.ForEach` loop be better here? The main issue I had with this is that the queue is being modified while we're looping over it, but a `Parallel.ForEach` loop assumes that you already have a complete collection. The two possibilities I came up with this:

- Just read the content of the files, and then do a `Parallel.ForEach` loop to do the regex.
- Process it on the background thread like I'm doing until we're done reading the file contents, then do a `Parallel.ForEach` loop over any remaining items once we're done.

What I have here works but is slower than I'd like. I'd definitely like feedback on the multithreading I'm doing here, especially if one of the possibilities I mentioned above would be better than what I'm doing (or if there's another possibility that I don't mention above).

```
namespace SearchByRegex
{
class Program
{
    // I should probably just move this out to its own file
    private class FilePair
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }

    private static ConcurrentQueue<FilePair> fileInformation = new ConcurrentQueue<FilePair>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Working...");

        // Command lines are a path followed by the regular expression
        var regex = new Regex(args[1], RegexOptions.Multiline);

        // Process
        Thread thread = new Thread(PrintInformationOnMatches);
        thread.Start(regex);

        SearchDirectory(args[0]);            

        while (fileInformation.Any())
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        thread.Abort();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Print information on all files whose content matches the <paramref name="regex"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="regex">Regex we're looking for</param>
    private static void PrintInformationOnMatches(object regex)
    {
        var castRegex = (Regex)regex;
        while (true)
        {
            // Process the entire queue
            while (fileInformation.Any())
            {
                FilePair pair;
                fileInformation.TryDequeue(out pair);

                if (castRegex.IsMatch(pair.Content))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"File name: {pair.FileName}. Path: {pair.FilePath}.");
                }
            }

            // Wait for more stuff on the queue
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the contents of the file and put them on the queue
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Path we are recursively searching</param>
    private static void SearchDirectory(string path)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

        //Console.WriteLine("Path: " + path);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            fileInformation.Enqueue(new FilePair { Content = File.ReadAllText(file), FilePath = path, FileName = file });
        }

        foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            SearchDirectory(directory);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> private static void SearchDirectory(string path)
> ```

This method does not need to be recursive. You could use the [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx) method

> ```
> Directory.EnumerateFiles Method (String, String, SearchOption)
> ```

where

> One of the (SearchOption) enumeration values that specifies whether the search operation should include only the current directory or should include all subdirectories.

I don't know how your regex looks like but for simple pattern with wildcards you can use the second parameter

> The search string to match against the names of files in path. This parameter can contain a combination of valid literal path and wildcard (* and ?) characters (see Remarks), but doesn't support regular expressions.

---

As far as the multithreading is concered you should definitely use the new TPL (`Parallel.ForEach`) instead of creating your own threads.

Answer (score 2):

Cool question! In addition to t3chb0t's great comments, I would suggest using a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`. It has additional support for blocking and bounding so you don't need to poll the queue manually, and you can limit the number of "in-flight" files. This could be used to make sure you don't read too many files into memory at once.

```
private static readonly BlockingCollection<FilePair> FilePairs =
    new BlockingCollection<FilePair>(10); // Limited to 10 files being processed at once.
```

Once you have finished adding all the files to the collection, call `FilePairs.CompleteAdding()`, and from the other thread, your while loop becomes:

```
foreach (var pair in FilePairs.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    ...
}
```

Another thing is that you are performing blocking IO when you call `File.ReadAllText()`, and you may want to consider using an `async` equivalent instead, freeing up more threads as you are reading. Also `Task.Run(() => PrintInformationOnMatches())` can be used instead of creating a `Thread`.

The [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) library could be used to achieve something similar, or for a simpler approach that kicks off parallel tasks for each file, you could use something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var matchTasks = Directory.EnumerateFiles(args[0], "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Select(async filePath =>
        {
            using (var reader = File.OpenText(filePath))
            {
                var fileContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                if (Regex.IsMatch(fileContent, args[1], RegexOptions.Multiline))
                    Console.WriteLine($"Found a match in {filePath}");
            }
        });

    Task.WaitAll(matchTasks.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

Comment: I like it when even from a _trivial_ question you can still learn a lot of new stuff ;-)